# What is python's unittest equivalent for BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I'm using the `unittest` framework and miss a functionality I have learned to love in `Boost.Test`. It is `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE`, and with its help one can run basically the same test for different types, for example

```cpp
typedef boost::mpl::vector<TypeA, TypeB> types_for_test;
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(test_something, T, types_for_test){
    T obj;
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(obj.empty(), true);
}
```

would result in two different unit tests: one for type `TypeA` and one for type `TypeB`.

However, I found nothing of the kind in the [`unittest`-documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html).

Thus my question: What is the standard way to emulate the  `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE`-functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of @Austin works fine (thanks a lot for that!). However, in my opinion, it is just too much boilerplate code.

Another possibility is to write a class decorator (let's call it `from_templates`) for `unittest.TestCase` class. The decorator would inspect the class, find the template methods and create real test cases for all needed types. For example:

```
import unittest

@from_templates([list, set, dict])
class TestBasics(unittest.TestCase):

    def template_is_empty(self, type4test):
        self.assertEquals(len(type4test()), 0)
```

would be roughly the same as

```
import unittest

class TestBasics(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_list_is_empty(self):
        self.assertEquals(len(list()), 0)

    def test_set_is_empty(self):
        self.assertEquals(len(set()), 0)

    def test_dict_is_empty(self):
        self.assertEquals(len(dict()), 0)
```

My implementation of this idea can be found here: https://github.com/realead/uttemplate

Answer (score 1):

Unittest doesn't have this functionality. You need to use the third-party pytest module, which has [extensive support](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) for parameterised testing.

Comment: There are two problems with this approach for me: I don't decide which frameworks should be used and even if I could, it looks like a lot of work to move old tests to this framework.

Comment: Well, unfortunately that's your only option; as I say, unittest doesn't support parameterisation. There is a [tool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2pytest/) to help with the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get there.

**Option 1**

The simplest way to do what you want using just `unittest` would probably be to inherit from a superclass that contains your test methods.

```
class templateMethodsForTesting:
    def test_foo(self):
        item = self.testclass("some args")
        assertEqual(item.foo, 1)

    def test_bar(self):
        item = self.testclass("other args")
        assertEqual(item.bar, 2)
```

Then inherit from unittest.Testcase as well as the template:

```
class testClass1(unittest.Testcase, templateMethodsForTesting):
    def __init__(self):
        self.testclass = Class1

class testClass2(unittest.Testcase, templateMethodsForTesting):
    def __init__(self):
        self.testclass = Class2
```

At this point, both classes will have the same method names, but will be different classes that are recognized by test discovery as deriving from Testcase.

The automatic discovery process should instantiate both, and invoke all the `test*` methods on both.

**Option 2**

Instead, you could parameterize a single test class with an object, or a class parameter, to the constructor (`__init__`). You would then have to handle creating the test cases yourself, and composing them into a suite.

Something like:

```
class testSeveralClasses(unittest.Testcase):
    def __init__(self, cls):
        self.obj = cls()
    def test_method1(self):
        assertEqual(self.obj.foo, 1)
```

However, the test builder won't know how to supply the `cls` argument, so you'll need to build a suite. Refer to the docs for all this.

Comment: I opted for option 1 and it works fine, I just needed to tweak `__init__` a little bit: `def __init__(self, *args):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, *args)
        self.testclass = Class2`. Did it work for you with your version?